# How do I display "image X of Y" in a Lightroom web engine Lua template?

Tags: lua, template-engine, lightroom

I'm creating a new "web engine" (i.e. gallery format) for Lightroom, which uses Lua templates to generate HTML for the gallery pages.

I've got both the SDK and Programmers Guide from here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshoplightroom/

But none of the SDK docs, examples, nor the Programmers Guide give me any hint of what variables I need to use to add, for example, "image 1 of 50" to the page heading.

There are a couple of objects, `$model` and `$image` which I suspect will have this information in - is there a way to dump the full data contained within these as text/html, so I can output to the HTML page and figure out what variable I want?

**Update:** half way there... found the variable `$index` which provides the current image number, so now I just need to figure out what/where the total count variable is.

Comment: As a Lua user who discovered Lua from reading the about box of the first beta release of LR for Windows, I'm surprised I don't actually know the answer...

Comment: Heh, well that at least reassures me I'm not being completely dim! :)

Comment: To be fair, I've done nothing with the LR SDK beyond download it and play with a sample or two... but I have been stuffing Lua into every project I can find the slimmest of excuses for ;-)

Answer (score 0):

On page 133 of the guide pdf it lists the variable "numImages". Is that what you need?